# Invalidate cached .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Working on launching a new site for a company. Prior to my work on the site, the company was redirecting traffic from their domain (call it realcompany.com) to a third party service (call it realcompany.thirdparty.com).

This was done via an htaccess file that does not specify any expiration time period.

The concern for launch, of course, is that existing users will wind up getting a cached htaccess file and will hit the old URL, not the new site.

Is there anything that can be done to invalidate the existing htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Force clearing the cache on local browser could help.

The below code clears the cache on local browser and sets a local variable so the process doesn't go into an infinite loop.

```
function clearCache() {
  var refreshed = localStorage.getItem('refreshed');

  if(refreshed===null){
  $.ajax({

  url: window.location.href,

  headers: {

    "Pragma": "no-cache",

    "Expires": -1,

    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"

  }

}).done(function () {

  window.location.reload(true);

});

localStorage.setItem('refreshed',"1");
  }

}
```